# How to uninitialize the entropy of /dev/urandom in C?

Tags: c, random, system-calls, libc

Is there a way to make that the entropy of /dev/urandom is and stay uninitialized?

My goal is to simulate an initialized or simply uninitialize /dev/urandom. How can I do a such thing?

edit: I see my question has been downvoted. I am sure the person who did has a legitimate reason. I have spent time searching the answer online but I didn't find anything.

Comment: You can't.  No better answer without knowing what you're trying to accomplish by doing so.

Comment: @indiv Thanks for the clarification. I would like to provoke a case where the entropy has not been initialized to make the generation of random number fail. So what I want to do is impossible?

Comment: As an aside, Linux now has a `getrandom` syscall that can replace use of `/dev/urandom`. It might block (once) if the entropy pool isn't yet initialized. This will generally only happen during early boot. OpenBSD has had a similar `getentropy` for a while.

Comment: @Greek2015:  Note that `/dev/urandom` will *never* fail to generate a pseudo-random sequence, even if there is no entropy.  You may get a predictable sequence, but it will appear random to any statistical test you throw at it...

Comment: @indiv Thank you, your answer is very interesting. How can I make that there is no entropy? I understand it is important for security, that's why I am interested in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As /dev/random and urandom are vital for security functions, allowing to tamper them would contradict their purpose. But you can add your own driver, or just replace calls to them with dummies (or use named pipes from a dummy for testing) instead.

Note: do not replace the driver on a production system.

Comment: How can I call them with dummies?

Comment: @Greek2015: dummy functions. Or a FIFO/named pipe with a dummy pseudo-random generator. Depends on what level you want to simulate.

Comment: @Greek2015: Change the spelling of `/dev/random` or `/dev/urandom` to `/dev/zero`; that will give you nicely non-random data.